# Python - Tkinter / manage size of parent window

Tags: python, tkinter

I set my Tkinter parent geometry and title like below:

```
from Tix import Tk

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.myParent = parent
        self.myParent.geometry("530x340")
        self.myParent.title("SSPFAT")


root = Tk()
myapp = MyApp(root)
```

The problem that I have is that: when I open the application depending on the screen resolution on different consoles the application GUI size will be slightly different and user would not see the entire application GUI.  Is there a way to automatically pack everything to the size specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to *not* set the size of the window. Instead, create appropriately sized widgets, use `grid` and/or `pack`, and let tkinter decide what the proper size of the window should be. Tkinter is extremely good at laying out the widgets.